# How can I disable provate browsing with selenium webdriver, and firefox browser?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my java code below. I use firefox profile settings. The problem is, I try to click a button, but the firefox tracking protection prevent the click. I tried to disable tracking protection, but if I turn off tracking protection mode, when the selenium driver open the browser, the browser forget my settings. I don't know why, and it's very annoying. How can I solve this problem?

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.setPreference("permissions.default.stylesheet", 2);
    profile.setPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);     
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\path\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();    
profile .setPreference("browser.private.browsing.autostart", false)
profile.setPreference("permissions.default.stylesheet", 2);
profile.setPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);     
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "F:\\path\\geckodriver.exe");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: Not working this: profile .setPreference("browser.private.browsing.autostart", false)

Comment: This is my error. I tried to click a button, that I'd like to display a value. It doesn't exist that value, and that class in the html structure, just if I click the button, but I can't, because of the tracking protection.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: I can't add the whole exception message, because it's too long.